# Why should bosons be in the adjoint representation of the gauge group?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, gauge-theory

Is there a deep mathematical reason for why [bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_boson) should be in the [adjoint representation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjoint_representation) of the [gauge group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_group_(mathematics)) rather than any other representation?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I guess by "bosons" you're referring to [gauge bosons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauge_boson)?

If so then start with some matter field  $ \psi(x)$  which transforms under the gauge group.  For local gauge transformations the gauge group element $g$ is spacetime dependent $g(x)$, and the transformation is
$$\psi(x) \longrightarrow \psi'(x) = g(x)\psi(x).$$

Derivatives would transform as

$$\partial_{\mu}\psi(x) \longrightarrow g(x)\partial_{\mu}\psi(x)+(\partial_{\mu}g(x))\psi(x),$$

i.e. inhomogeneously.  We would like a gauge covariant derivative $D_{\mu}$ which transforms homogeneously as

$$D_{\mu}\psi(x) \longrightarrow g(x)D_{\mu}\psi(x).$$

To achieve this, we define

$$D_{\mu}\psi = \partial_{\mu}\psi - A_{\mu}\psi,$$
where $A_{\mu} = \mathbf{A}_{\mu} \cdot\boldsymbol{{\tau}}$ and $\boldsymbol{\tau}$ are the generators of the Lie algebra of the gauge group and $A_{\mu}$ is our bosonic gauge field.  This introduction of gauge bosons via the derivative term is sometimes referred to as [minimal coupling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimal_coupling).

In order to achieve this, $A_{\mu}$ is forced to have the transformation law

$$A_{\mu} \longrightarrow A'_{\mu} = gA_{\mu}g^{-1} + (\partial_{\mu}g)g^{-1}.$$

Just looking at how the $A_{\mu}$ are transforming under the group action (the first term), we recognize the adjoint representation.

Of course, on the global stage, the fields $\psi$ can be interpreted as bundle sections and the gauge fields as bundle connections.  $A_\mu$'s transformation law will be recognisable as a transformation of connection coefficients under the action of the bundle's structure group.  A good reference is [Nakahara](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0852740956), or this [link](http://www.nikhef.nl/~t45/ftip/Ch12.pdf).

Comment: Why do we still say A is in the adjoint representation if there is that second term?

Comment: @Lagrangian It's answer here: http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/191982/21817. They transform in the adjoint under global transformations.

Comment: But, as far as I understand, we can use what you called \vec{\tau} in any representation of the group, including the fundamental. So why should we continue to interpret this as the adjoint representation? I mean, it is true that the gauge field transforms in the adjoint representation, i.e. g^-1 A g, but this seems to contradict my previous idea. I think I am missing something very important.