# Why $W^+$ and $W^-$ bosons counted as two types of particles? but not $e^+$ and $e^-$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, standard-model, gauge-theory, weak-interaction

The [$W^+$ and $W^-$ bosons have either a positive or negative electric charge of 1 elementary charge and are each other's antiparticles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/W_and_Z_bosons).

In this sense, if we know the properties of $W^+$, we should know all the properties of its antiparticle $W^-$.

Similarly, the positron $e^+$ and electron $e^-$ have a positive or negative electric charge of 1 elementary charge and are each other's antiparticles. If we know the properties of $e^-$, we should know all the properties of its antiparticle $e^+$.

In the particle physics, *we do not list the positron $e^+$ and electron $e^-$ as two types of elementary particles. We only count the electron $e^-$ as an elementary particle. ($e^+$ is just its antiparticle) *

> However, in the particle physics, *we do list $W^+$ and $W^-$ bosons as two types of elementary particles - two distinct gauge bosons -- so why is that?*

Source:
[image]

Comment: What is your definition of "type of elementary particle" and what is your reference that we count the W/Z bosons as distinct in this sense but not e.g. the 8 gluons? Also, are we talking about the theory before or after the breaking of the electroweak symmetry?

Comment: "8 gluons are elementary" in the sense of standard particle physics. Before or after the breaking of the electroweak gauge symmetry does not affect whether and how we count   +  and  −. It only gives masses to  +  and  − after the breaking of the electroweak gauge symmetry

Comment: I think my question should be clear what I am aiming at.

Comment: We do say $SU(2)$ weak have 3 distinct gauge bosons. It is probably easier to see in the unbroken $SU(2)$ basis. But I am writing in the later basis of $SU(2) \times U(1) \to U(1)_{em}$

Comment: Perhaps, we do count  + and − as two kinds of particles. The − $L$ and  + $R$ as one Weyl fermion particle. The − $R$ and  + $L$ as another Weyl fermion particle

Comment: It is *not* clear. What source counts $W$ differently from $e$?

Comment: Veltman’s book lists all antifermions as well, to total 61 particles, no?

Comment: Add Source: Wikipedia, we do not just write $W$ but +  and − in the usual particle textbook.

Comment: I get your question now. You are asking why that diagram says $W^\pm$ instead of $W$, since it just says $e$, not $e^\pm$. This is because somebody made an inconsistent diagram for Wikipedia.

Comment: Look at [this diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Model#/media/File:Standard_Model_of_Elementary_Particles.svg). No $W^\pm$. But it mentions that $W$ comes in two charges, but doesn’t mention that for other charged particles. Lesson: Don’t take Wikipedia diagrams too literally.

Answer (score 1):

Honestly, I think it stems from the "importance" associated with there being 4 electroweak gauge bosons in the context of the Higgs mechanism and spontaneous symmetry breaking.

The electroweak interaction stems from the gauge theory of a $SU(2)_L \times U(1)_Y$ symmetry, which has $4$ degrees of freedom: $3$ from $SU(2)$ ($n^2  -1 = 4 - 1$) and $1$ from $U(1)$. Upon making this symmetry *local*, we need $4$ *gauge* fields to accompany each of the $4$ generators of the group above. After the Higgs mechanism and hence spontaneous symmetry breaking, the symmetry is broken to a simple $U(1)$, which only has one degree of freedom. The $3$ broken generators give mass to as many of the (hitherto massless) gauge bosons. These gauge fields are mixed and result in $3$ massive fields, $W^+, W^-$ and $Z^0$, and $1$ massless field - the photon. 
 Making sure these numbers add up to $4$, and that the massive ones are $3$ $=$ number of broken group generators, is usually 80% of what people talk about when discussing SSB and Higgs.

Electrons and positrons are indeed *distinct* elementary particles. 
 Famously, the [Dirac equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_equation), describing particles with spin $s = 1/2$, is only solved by a $1\times 4$ object called a *spinor*. These $4$ degrees of freedom are taken to represent electrons and positrons with spin up/down. So matter and antimatter here are clearly independent. 
 But I think there isn't as much of a strict need of a reminder that there's "two of everything" when dealing with leptons (excluding neutrinos for now) and quarks. I mean, there is a mathematical requirement, namely the spinor being a $4$-entry object.

The same thing goes for gluons, as mentioned in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

What you show is the particle table of elementary particles. There exists an antiparticle table which is not usually shown, and it again will show the middle column the same as in the particle table.

The vector bosons have the same function in both tables, particle and antiparticle of mediating the interactions .

It is all a matter of clarity, imo.